# What does "discouraged reference" mean in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I noticed this setting in Eclipse's compiler settings. How is this different than a "forbidden reference"?

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/access_rules.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse has Internal packages that are not intended for use by downstream plug-ins. However, these packages are visible to downstream plug-ins by default.

A discouraged reference is a reference in your code to one of the Eclipse internal packages.

You can find more information in the Plug-in Development Environment Guide -> Tools -> Editors -> Plug-in manifest editor -> Plug-in run time -> Access Rules.

Comment: Your answer does not explain the difference between a discouraged and forbidden reference. A link would've been faster; and your downmod (presuming if it were you) was a little rude considering a comment alone would have sufficed. I understand that maybe I've gotten a little link happy, and I'll take your advice to heart, but I think a little mercy goes a long way.

Comment: @BeardedO:  True, my answer is incomplete.  I used the Help in my open Eclipse, so I didn't have an Internet link.  Showing someone the breadcrumbs trail, as well as a link, is probably the most helpful.  P.S.  I've made 6 downvotes in 6 months.  I think I'm pretty tolerant.

Comment: Well lets just set this behind us, and learn whatever there is to be learned from it. I imagine your intentions were pure and perhaps you had simply misread my post.

Answer (score 3):

From a comment on the accepted answer on [how to open the find type dialog programmatically in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218801/how-to-open-the-find-type-dialog-programmatically-in-eclipse)

> You get a discouraged access warning
>   whenever you reference a type in a
>   package that is not part of the API,
>   typically these are *.internal
>   packages. "Discouraged access" is an
>   indicator that you should look for an
>   API alternative if possible. Be aware
>   that you might be vulnerable to change
>   in later versions of Eclipse. See
>   help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp for
>   more details – Rich Seller

Answer (score 1):

a [discouraged refrence](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/editors/manifest_editor/access_rules.htm) is one that throws a warning by default whereas a forbidden reference is one that throws an error. They are similar contraindications but they differ in severity.

Comment: Your answer does not explain what a discouraged reference is.